# Doubts on using Apple Passbook

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, passbook

Am trying to develop a coupon using Apple Passbook. My scenario is i have a web server from which i have to send the offers to iPhone as a Coupon. I tried to understand about the communication how happens between them, but not clear about it. Can anyone suggest me,

- How can i send the offers from my web server to iPhone as passbook?
- Where i have to store my data either in my database or anyway we have to store in iphone?
- If user views a coupon sent by us, how the user can use the coupon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- How can i send the offers from my web server to iPhone as passbook?

The process is as follows:

1. Create a pass containing your `webserviceURL` and `authenticationToken`
2. Once the user adds the pass to Passbook, their device will register with your web service and provide you with a device id and device token.
3. Update your pass database with the new offer information
4. Send an empty push message to the device token (from step 2) using the certificate (`passTypeIdentifier`) from the pass
5. The device will receive the push and will contact your web service for a list of updated serials
6. Your web service returns the serial number(s) of the pass(es) that you wish to update
7. The device then request the updated pass(es)
8. Your web service sends the new pass(es)

See [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) for details on the web service specification.  Also note that your production web service must use https.

- Where i have to store my data either in my database or anyway we have to store in iphone?

In your database. The iPhone will only hold the information necessary to display the pass (in the pass.json file).  Your database will need to hold details such as the last updated time and the device id and device token.  There is a sample database available as part of the ruby server example in Apple's [Passbook Support Materials](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=passbook) *(Apple developer account required)*

- If user views a coupon sent by us, how the user can use the coupon?

That is entirely up to you - a passbook coupon is no different to a paper coupon.  It is up to the pass issuer to decide how they wish to use it.  In the most simple case, the issuer could scan the code, then send a request to update your database (with let's say 'status = redeemed'), your server then follows the steps above to push a new pass to the device showing the user that the pass has been redeemed.

Comment: That's very clear and perfect explanation. Thanks a lot to you. One more doubt i have if i use email option for passbook then how my web server will send the coupon to iPhone?

Comment: @sabarish, if you want to send the pass as an email attachment, you would use the same code that you use to generate your .pkpass bundle, then attach the .pkpass file to an email (be sure to add the mime type of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`.  However, passes may become stale, certificates expire, etc. so rather than send the .pkpass bundle, it's better (and easier) to send a URL where the user can download the latest version of their pass.